# Memory efficient map for byte array values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm trying to load huge amounts of data into a `HashMap`. At the moment I'm trying pushing 20 million entries. When loading this amount of entries into this map I noticed that quite a lot of memory is consumed considering that all I'm loading into this map is byte arrays (I'm generating this data from 500mb file, each byte array on average has size of 5 and at most 11):

```java
Map<Key, byte[]> result = new HashMap<>(entryCount, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
    do {
        // Read data from file, store it into result and increment count.
    } while (count < MAX_COUNT);   
}
```

And the `Key` class:

```java
public final class Key {

    private final byte[] value;

    Key(byte[] value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

Looking up whats consuming this much memory using `jProfiler`, I noticed that `HashMap$Node` is one of the classes in top of the charts:
[image]

I'm curious are there more memory efficient `Map` implementations for this exact type of data?

Comment: You are using 26 meg to store 20 meg... do you have ~100k arrays in that `Map`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm storing 20 million arrays. What I'm wondering is that are there any map implementations which do not create a `Node` for each map element. And maybe there are specialized map implementations for this specific type of data that I'm storing.

Comment: The class `Key`has an instance variable `byte[] value`. And the value type of the  `result` map is `byte[]` too. Do you put for a key `k` its value in the map: `result.put(k, k.getValue())`? This would be redundant. The map would be unnecessary as you need to know the key `k` to get the value from the map: `result.get(k)`. But if you have the key `k`, so you have its value: `k.getValue()`. Then there is no need for the map.

Comment: @LuCio `key` and the value that I put inside the map are completely unrelated. The key is actually an `md5` hash. While the value consists of bytes read from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type-specific map, as in fastutil or trove etc. For example, you can use Object2ByteArrayMap in fastutil which meets your requirement.

[The fastuil api](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/index.html?overview-summary.html)

Comment: `Object2ByteArrayMap` only uses byte array internally and only allows to store 1 byte per key (not an array). Also reading the [javadoc](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2ByteArrayMap.html) it seems that this data structure was built for a small number of entries.

Comment: @Edd Yes, you're right. Have you tried `Object2ObjectMap`? Or may be you can custom your own map.

Comment: Yes I did. It was chugging at few thousand entries so I scratched the idea.